how to add scrollbar to expression label on my calculator or to make the expression become small as my expression expands on calculator
I'm new at python and currently learning GUI tkinter in python, I am very much inspired by the code of a tic-tac-toe game and thought that what if I could make calculator out of it, so I tried and achieved the program of best of my capabilities and made a very well calculator, but I don't really know how to add a scrollbar with horizontal orient or to make equations text small as the expression becomes big like in mobile calculators, so I need your help with it and also rate my code for calculator like what I could have improved? and what I shouldn't have done.
here's my whole code -->
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

initial_expression = ''

def onclick(row, column):

    value = buttons[row][column]['text']

    global initial_expression
    initial_expression = initial_expression + value

    equation.set(initial_expression) 

def clear():

    equation.set(' ')
    global initial_expression
    initial_expression = ''

def solve():

    try :

        global initial_expression
        evaluate_expression = str(eval(initial_expression))
        equation.set(evaluate_expression)
        initial_expression = evaluate_expression

    except:

        equation.set('Error')
        initial_expression = ''

def delete_last_string():

    try:
        global initial_expression
        element_list = []
        element_index = 0
        for element in initial_expression:
            element_list = element_list + [element]
            element_index += 1
        final_index = element_index - 1    
        element_list.remove(element_list[final_index])

        new_element = ''
        for element in element_list:
            new_element = new_element + element
        initial_expression = new_element
        equation.set(initial_expression)

    except:
        equation.set(' ')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Calculator')

equation = StringVar()
equation.set('')

button_text = [['+','-','*','/'],
              ['1','2','3','C'],
              ['4','5','6','='],
              ['7','8','9','.'],
              ['0','(',')','<-']]

buttons = [[0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0]]

operators = ['+','-','*','/','=','C','.','(',')','<-']

expression_label = Label(window, textvariable = equation, font = ('consolas',50))
expression_label.pack(side = 'top', pady = 10, padx = 10)

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

for row in range(5):
    for column in range(4):

        buttons[row][column] = Button(frame, width = 5, height = 1, font = ('consolas',30),
                                  text = button_text[row][column])
        buttons[row][column].grid(row = row, column = column)

        for operator in button_text[row][column]:

            if operator in operators:

                buttons[row][column].config(bg = 'orange', activebackground = 'brown', activeforeground = 'white')

                if buttons[row][column]['text'] != 'C' and buttons[row][column]['text'] != '=' and buttons[row][column]['text'] != '<-':

                   buttons[row][column].config(command = lambda row = row, column = column : onclick(row, column))

                elif buttons[row][column]['text'] == 'C':

                    buttons[row][column].config(command = clear)

                elif buttons[row][column]['text'] == '=':

                    buttons[row][column].config(command = solve)

                elif buttons[row][column]['text'] == '<-':

                    buttons[row][column].config(command = delete_last_string)

            else:
        
                buttons[row][column].config(bg = 'lightgrey', activebackground = 'grey')
                buttons[row][column].config(command = lambda row = row, column = column : 
onclick(row,column))

window.mainloop()


This code has some indentation errors that prevent it from running

sorry for that, but now I edited the code and it works properly so check it out and pls tell me the way

One solution is to change expression_label from a tk.Label to a tk.Entry widget like this.
expression_label = Entry(window, textvariable = equation, width = 13, font = ('consolas',50))

You can also add a horizontal scrollbar if you wish, like this.
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(window, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL, command = expression_label.xview)
scroll.pack(fill="both")
expression_label.config(xscrollcommand = scroll.set)


entry widget works, but it always places the expressions to the left if I need it to be set right what should I do? and the second one doesn't work saying 'label object has no method xview' and thanks for your reply

The Entry widget has  a justify property that's preset to left, you may change it to left, right or center.

A Label widget has no scrollbar functionality, but Entry does. So your second problem implies you haven't changed 'expression_label' to the Entry widget!?

thank you it worked so well and yes now I changed it to entry widget and can scroll horizontally
